# Java arraylist of graphics

Tags: java, graphics, arraylist

How can I store an ArrayList of graphics so that I can then call a drawString() command on a specific ArrayList position?

For example this is what I want but none of the code works :(

```
ArrayList<Graphics> list= new ArrayList<Graphics>();
//create a certain number of graphics
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
     list.add(new Graphics[i] = null);
}
//run drawString on a certain array value independently of the others
((Graphics) columns.get(2)).drawString("v", 50, 50);
((Graphics) columns.get(4)).drawString("xx", 10, 100);
```

Comment: Usually, you'd get your Graphics from an object like a Panel or a BufferedImage, rather than creating it with a constructor. Also, you seem to be storing arrays of Graphics in that list. Why do you want a heap of Graphics, rather than just one?

Comment: Because i would like to have more than one piece of text displayed on the screen at once, hence the multiple images. But I would like to move each piece of text by itself hence the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can't store an ArrayList of Grapics.

Custom painting is done by overriding the paintComponent() method of JPanel. Then in that method you iterate over the Strings that you want to paint using the Grapics object of the paintComponent() method.

Check out the `Draw On Component` example from [Custom Painting Approaches](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/). The example draws a series of rectangles stored in an ArrayList, but the concept is the same.